# control facebooks fb-like-box style with css

Tags: jquery, css, facebook

I am using `SOCIAL PLUGINS` `LIKE BOX` 
and would like to control the styling [beyond what FB gives you here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

this example i am trying to hide the icon with no luck
**question**: how do you target this iframe to control its elements?
heres my code in `css`

```
.fb-like-box .connect_top a img{display:none !important;}
```

and with `jQuery`

```
$('.fb-like-box .connect_top a img').css({'display':'none'});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this HTML :

```
<iframe id="fb_like_box" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<URL TO YOUR PAGE>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

But replace  with real url to page to like.

Comment: that did it, where can i find a list of attributes like `show_faces`? now im trying to hide the `pluginCountButton`

Comment: this made it as plain as possible `#fb_like_box{clear:both; width:45px; height:25px; display:block; margin-bottom:40px;}`

Comment: You can not access to DOM of iframe of plugin box because iframe loads from another domain(from facebok.com).

Comment: If you want to use like box without some elements then try ti use : [Like button plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: yes, thats what i originally used but it does not give you full control